After Spring Boot upgrade 3.1.1 , Hibernate Interceptor Post flush method not invoked after entity saved
After upgrading Spring boot version from 2.5.8 to 3.1.1 , Hibernate Interceptor post flush method is not getting invoked but when added hibernate property  "hibernate.session_factory.interceptor" post flush method  is invoked.
Can anyone please explain the difference between "hibernate.session_factory.interceptor" vs "hibernate.ejb.interceptor"hibernate properties.
Added hibernate property  "hibernate.session_factory.interceptor" post flush method  is invoked.
